# Global Exception Handling in Play Application

Tags: scala, rest, playframework, playframework-2.0

currently I'm implementing a REST API with Scala and the Play! Framework. When a user submits data da is not correct, or the user is not allowed to view a resource the API has to response with BadRequest or Forbidden.

I don't want to have a huge bulk of nested if-else-statements to check every permission. So I just want to raise RuntimeExceptions like BadRequestException or ForbiddenException.

```
class MapableRestException(msg: String) extends RuntimeException(msg)
class NotFoundException(msg: String) extends MapableRestException(msg)
class ForbiddenException(msg: String) extends MapableRestException(msg)
class BadRequestException(msg: String) extends MapableRestException(msg)
```

In the Global Class I override onError

```
override def onError(request: RequestHeader, ex: Throwable): Future[Result] = ex.getCause match {
  case notfound: NotFoundException => {
    Future.successful(NotFound(JsonHelper.toJsonAll(ErrorDTO(notfound.getMessage()))).as(JSON))
  }

  case forbidden: ForbiddenException => {
    Future.successful(Forbidden(JsonHelper.toJsonAll(ErrorDTO(forbidden.getMessage()))).as(JSON))
  }

  case badrequest: BadRequestException => {
    Future.successful(BadRequest(JsonHelper.toJsonAll(ErrorDTO(badrequest.getMessage))).as(JSON))
  }

  case _ => super.onError(request, ex)
```

}

But when an one of the above Exceptions is thrown the stacktrace is still printed on the console?

Greetings,
Daniel

Comment: When you use ex and not ex.getCause everything is a PlayException

Comment: So that works but you don't want to see the stacktrace of those exceptions in the console/logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too would be interested in a more direct answer to this, but for the meantime, here's a workaround.

Create an `ActionBuilder` that runs your block and uses `recover` (or `recoverWith`, if you need to do async stuff) to do your global error handling, then use it in place of `Action`:

```
object ActionWithErrorHandling extends ActionBuilder[Request] {
  override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
    block(request) recover {
      case e: PermissionDenied => Forbidden(e.getMessage)
      case e: ItemNotFound => NotFound(e.getMessage)
    }
  }
}
```

And in controllers:

```
def myAction = ActionWithErrorHandling { implicit request =>
  // Non-exception code path...
}
```

This is arguably a more sanitary approach since it preserves the Global onError for genuine oh-dear situations.